# How can I scroll a bash script up from within the script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, macos

I'm printing a big ANSI picture in my terminal and it's bigger than the size of the terminal. When I print out the picture the terminal scrolls to the bottom of the picture. Is there any way I can scroll back up from with the script to see the top of the picture? I've tried using `tput ri` but that just pushes up the previous lines. I'd also like to accomplish this without installing any extra programs (I'm on a Mac). Using `less` doesn't properly display the picture.

Answer (score 1):

`file.txt | less -R`

The `-R` option on `less` (or `more`) allows ANSI characters to be interpreted.